# how to add a UIBarButtonSystemItem icon to a TableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview

can't figure out how to add icons to tableViewCell. I've seen that UIBarButtonSystemItem icons are Used in toolbar but can not find any example that shows using 'system icons' anywhere else, is there a way or should I find some other icon library and implement icons as a ImageView?:S